# iOS app of xcode 6 not run properly in iOS7 , app leave the some black space from top and bottom

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios8, xcode6, screen-size

I am creating an ios app in xocde 6 and it run in simulator ( iphone5 iOS 8.0) it work very well. But it not work in iphone 5 iOS 7.0 simulator or iphone iOS 7.0 device. App leave some space from top and bottom .So please help me how can resolve it.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First thing is that you must add the required **default image** for 4 inch screen display. Check Properly in you project have image with name **Default-568h@2x.png** (640 × 1136 pixels)

Ones you add this image in to you Project, Remove old Build from device or Simulator, clear Project and re build.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have launch image to resolve that issue , try with launch of proper dimensions.